# Flutter: Android Gradle plugin mismatch when trying to upgrade

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to upgrade my current flutter project to use the latest flutter sdk. Currently my project is using 3.7.x, I'm trying to upgrade to be able to use 3.13.x.

Besides that, currently there are many old packages in the project. So I'm upgrading all of the packages to use the latest stable version.

However, along the way, when I tried running on Android, I faced the following problem.

```
The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':desktop_drop' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20
```

When I checked which package depends on 'desktop_drop', I found out it was stream_chat_flutter(6.9.0).

My initial assumption was that desktop_drop is not supported on 3.13.x. However, when I tried creating a new flutter project using flutter create <new_project> (with flutter 3.13.x) and have stream_chat_flutter as one of the dependencies, it can build just fine. Because of this I believe I've made a mistake when trying to upgrade the gradle.

I tried upgrading and downgrading the gradle version but I think I'm not doing it correctly.

Can anyone assist on this issue. What's the right way to perform gradle ugprade.

What I've done so far:-

I changed the following

1. I tried AGP Upgrade Assistant
2. Changing the android/build.gradle, android/app/build.gradle, and android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties